API Versioning Graphql
Does anyone know how to implement API versioning in GraphQL with NestJS? I don't want to change the name of the resolver; I only want to change the GraphQL URL from http://localhost:3003/graphql/v1 to http://localhost:3003/graphql/v2. I am currently trying to do API versioning in GraphQL and I am using NestJS and TypeORM.
